# styled-components is saying wrapped styled() around your React component (Component)

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, codesandbox

I have my app in CodeSandbox using styled-component. Please refer the below url
https://lrn6vmq297.sse.codesandbox.io/

Everytime I made some changes, the console is saying.

`` Warning: Prop `className` did not match. ``

`It looks like you've wrapped styled() around your React component (Component), but the className prop is not being passed down to a child. No styles will be rendered unless className is composed within your React component.`

and UI does not render as expected. 
Anyone has idea why I am having this issue ? Please have a look the url above.

Thanks

Comment: The  codesandbox can't show necessary code.Please update it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, you need to pass `this.props.className` or `props.className` or a deconstructed `className` that was generated by `styled-components` and manually apply it to the component you want to style. Otherwise, you're not applying the `className` to anything and therefore won't see any style changes.

**Working example:**

[image: Edit Styled Component]

**components/LinkComponent.js** (this `functional component` accepts the `className` generated by `styled()` and `props` that were passed in to the styled component created below -- you'll need to manually apply them to the `Link` component)

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const LinkComponent = ({ className, children, link }) => (
  <Link className={className} to={link}>
    {children}
  </Link>
);

LinkComponent.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  link: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default LinkComponent;
```

**components/StyledLink.js** (import the `functional component` above and pass it to `styled()` -- you can also create a [styled themed](https://codesandbox.io/s/l2wl3866kq) to update `styled()` elements)

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import LinkComponent from "./LinkComponent";

const StyledLink = styled(LinkComponent)`
  color: ${props => (!props.primary && !props.danger ? "#03a9f3" : "#ffffff")};
  background-color: ${props => {
    if (props.primary) return "#03a9f3";
    if (props.danger) return "#f56342";
    return "transparent";
  }};
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid
    ${props => {
      if (props.primary) return "#03a9f3";
      if (props.danger) return "#f56342";
      return "#03a9f3";
    }};

  &:hover {
    color: ${props => (!props.primary && !props.danger ? "#0f7ae5" : "#ffffff")};
    background-color: ${props => {
      if (props.primary) return "#0f7ae5";
      if (props.danger) return "#be391c";
      return "transparent";
    }};
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid ${props => (props.danger ? "#be391c" : "#0f7ae5")}};
  }
`;

export default StyledLink;
```

**components/Header.js** (import the styled component `StyledLink` created above and utilize it -- any additional props passed to this component will automatically be passed to the `function`, however, you'll need to, in this case, deconstruct the `prop` to utilize it)

```
import React from "react";
import StyledLink from "./StyledLink";

export default () => (
  <nav className="container">
    <StyledLink primary link="/">Home</StyledLink>
    <StyledLink danger link="/about">About</StyledLink>
    <StyledLink link="/portfolio">Portfolio</StyledLink>
  </nav>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation where I would need to use a component created by styled-component, and pass css property to that component. Hope this helps!

**Main component** (define CSS property here)

```js
import Wrapper from 'components/Wrapper'

const CustomWrapper = styled(Wrapper)`
  &:hover {
    background-color: blue;  // defining css property I want to pass down
  }
`;
...

render() {
  return (
    ... <CustomWrapper />  // using my CustomWrapper component made from 'styled-component'
  )
}
`;
```

**Wrapper.js - functional component** (use defined CSS here)

```js
const Wrapper = props => {
  const { className } = props;  // see how className is destructed and used below

  return (
    <div className={className}>  // 'className' is used here
      {YOUR_CONTENT}
    </div>  
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Link doesn't really work (or I don't understand what exactly you wanted to show), but from the error message it looks like you should pass className like this
`styled(<Component className={your source for classnames} />)`

Answer (score 0):

For shared components it's better to use forwardRef, or you can just pass props:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

function MainComponent() {
  return (
    <LoadingStyled />
  )
})

const LoadingStyled = styled(LoadingComponent)`
  margin-top: 40px;
`
```

---

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'

export const LoadingComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div {...props}>
      I got all props and styles, yeeeee!
    </div>
  )
})
```

---

Alternative without forwardRef.

```
import React from 'react'

export const LoadingComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div {...props}>
      I got all props and styles, yeeeee!
    </div>
  )
}
```