# Styled components without support of className property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, intl-tel-input

I am using react and styled components and use 3rd party component named IntlTelInput.
My code goes like this:

```
const StyledIntlTelInput = styled(IntlTelInput)`
    background: blue;
`;

export default function PhoneNumberInput() {
    return (
        <StyledIntlTelInput />
    );
}
```

`IntlTelInput` doesn't support className property, but `containerClassName`. As a result I get the IntlTelInput without blue background.
How can I solve this?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332428/styled-components-is-saying-wrapped-styled-around-your-react-component-compon/53333912#53333912 Just pass the `className` generated by `styled-components` into the `IntlTelInput`'s `containerClassName` property.

Comment: The problem gets bigger because the component itself support className from the outside...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add some wrapper component wich translate `containerClassName` to `className`.

```
const MyWrapper = ({ className, ...props }) => (
    return <IntlTelInput containerClassName={className} {...props} />;
);

const StyledIntlTelInput = styled(MyWrapper)`
    background: blue;
`;
```