# "It looks like you've wrapped styled() around your React component (Hero), but the className prop is not being passed down to a child."?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I have a Hero component that I'm using to display hero images on my blog posts. Everything seems to be working correctly but I'm getting this warning in the console:

`"It looks like you've wrapped styled() around your React component (Hero), but the className prop is not being passed down to a child. No styles will be rendered unless className is composed within your React component.`

Here is the code for my Hero component:

```
// /components/Hero.js

import React from 'react'
import BgImg from 'gatsby-background-image'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Hero = props => (
    <BgImg Tag="section"
      className="hero is-large"
       fluid={props.headerImage.childImageSharp.fluid}
       >
       <div className="hero-body">
       </div>
     </BgImg>
);

const StyledHero = styled(Hero)`
  width: 100%;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: cover;
`

export default StyledHero
```

Why am I getting this warning and how can I fix it?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332428/styled-components-is-saying-wrapped-styled-around-your-react-component-compon/53333912#53333912

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you do not pass the `className` to any internal component, thus the styles you've specified in `StyledHero` do not get applied.

The way to make it working (and also get rid of the warning) is to pass the `className` down like this:

```
const Hero = props => (
    <BgImg Tag="section"
       className={`${props.className} hero is-large`}
       fluid={props.headerImage.childImageSharp.fluid}
       >
       <div className="hero-body">
       </div>
     </BgImg>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

This was a warning in the styled-components package that I think the dev's have addressed.
https://github.com/styled-components