# Dependency cycle issue when using Styled Components alongside compound component pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a few accordion components created using the compound component methodology (there is a great talk by Ryan Florence describing compound components [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEGg-3pIHlE)).

One of the ESLint rules I have setup is [import/no-cycle](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.17.3/docs/rules/no-cycle.md) to prevent dependency cycles. As I'm using the compound component methodology as well as the advised way to [refer to other components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components) in Styled Components by keeping all styles relevant to a particular component in that file itself, I am triggering the import/no-cycle warning.

Here is my Accordion.js file.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import AccordionTrigger from "./accordionTrigger";
import AccordionContent from "./accordionContent";

const Accordion = ({ children, show }) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(show);

  const handleTriggerClick = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive);
  };

  const compoundChildren = React.Children.map(children, child => {
    switch (child.type) {
      case AccordionTrigger:
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          onClick: handleTriggerClick,
          active: isActive ? 1 : 0,
        });

      case AccordionContent:
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          show: isActive,
        });

      default:
        return child;
    }
  });

  return <div show={show ? 1 : 0}>{compoundChildren}</div>;
};

export default Accordion;
```

And my AccordionTrigger.js file.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import FauxButton from "../buttons/fauxButton";

import Accordion from "./accordion";
import TopLevelTrigger from "./topLevelTrigger";
import SecondaryLevelTrigger from "./secondaryLevelTrigger";

const Root = styled(FauxButton)`
  ${Accordion} & {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid ${p => p.theme.greyLight};
  }
`;

const AccordionTrigger = ({ active, children, ...rest }) => {
  const clonedChildren = React.Children.map(children, child => {
    switch (child.type) {
      case TopLevelTrigger:
      case SecondaryLevelTrigger:
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          active,
        });

      default:
        return child;
    }
  });
  return <Root {...rest}>{clonedChildren}</Root>;
};

export default AccordionTrigger;
```

One thing I have tried is defining the `AccordionTrigger` styles in `Accordion.js` like so...

```
const Root = styled.div`
  ${AccordionTrigger} & {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid ${p => p.theme.greyLight};
  }
`;

const Accordion = ({ children, show }) => {
  ...same logic as before here

  return <Root show={show ? 1 : 0}>{compoundChildren}</Root>;
};
```

...but this doesn't work, the styles simply don't get added to the `AccordionTrigger` component. I know I can simply add my own class via the `className` prop when cloning inside of the `Accordion` component and then refer to it that way but I was wondering if there was a way to prevent this?

Comment: const Root = styled.div`
  ${AccordionTrigger} 
  } .  How are you adding a component in style? This is not correct

Comment: @kishorekingmaker See https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components. It is the recommended way of referring to other components.

Comment: See it, You can access component like this .  const AComponent = styled(({props}) => <BComponent ...props/>)` styles`

Comment: I will write an answer so that you can better understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, `styled-components` generates a `className` that **must** be applied to an `HTML/JSX Element` in order to see styles. In addition, the composed component **must be an instance of a styled component**. My example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332428/styled-components-is-saying-wrapped-styled-around-your-react-component-compon/53333912#53333912) explains a basic approach to styling a custom component.

Since, I don't have your full code, I recreated the example from the video you linked.

**Working example** (in this case, I'm styling `TabContent` within `Tab` and altering its `svg` element):

[image: Edit cool-sinoussi-spdpq]

In addition, I structured my files like so, which avoids the import recursion issues:

```
├── src
|   ├── components
|   |   ├── Tab
|   |   |   ├── Tab.js
|   |   |   └── index.js
|   |   |
|   |   ├── TabContent
|   |   |   ├── TabContent.js
|   |   |   └── index.js
|   |   | 
|   |   ├── TabList
|   |   |   └── index.js
|   |   | 
|   |   ├── TabPanel
|   |   |   └── index.js
|   |   | 
|   |   ├── TabPanels
|   |   |   ├── TabPanels.js
|   |   |   └── index.js
|   |   | 
|   |   └── Tabs
|   |       └── index.js
|   └── index.js
|
├── index.js
└── tabs.js
```

---

**src/components/Tab/Tab.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Tab = ({ children, className, disabled, onSelectTab }) => (
  <div className={className} onClick={disabled ? null : onSelectTab}>
    {children}
  </div>
);

Tab.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  onSelectTab: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Tab;
```

**src/components/Tab/index.js**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Tab from "./Tab";
import TabContent from "../TabContent";

export default styled(Tab)`
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  ${({ disabled, isActive }) => {
    if (disabled) return `opacity: 0.25; cursor: default;`;
    if (isActive) return `color: #1890ff; border-bottom-color: #1890ff;`;
  }}

  &:hover {
    color: #40a9ff;
    border-bottom-color: #40a9ff;
    ${({ disabled }) =>
      disabled &&
      `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65); border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);`};
  }

  ${TabContent} {
    & svg {
      font-size: 13px;
    }
  }
`;
```

**src/components/TabContent/TabContent.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const TabContent = ({ children, className }) => (
  <div className={className}>{children}</div>
);

TabContent.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export default TabContent;
```

**src/components/TabContent/index.js**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import TabContent from "./TabContent";

export default styled(TabContent)`
  font-size: 20px;
`;
```

**src/components/TabList/index.js**

```
import { Children, cloneElement, useCallback } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const TabList = ({ activeIndex, children, setActiveIndex }) => {
  const handleSelectedTab = useCallback(
    index => {
      setActiveIndex(index);
    },
    [setActiveIndex]
  );

  return Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
    cloneElement(child, {
      isActive: activeIndex === index,
      onSelectTab: () => handleSelectedTab(index)
    })
  );
};

TabList.propTypes = {
  activeIndex: PropTypes.number,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  setActiveIndex: PropTypes.func
};

export default TabList;
```

**src/components/TabPanel/index.js**

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const TabPanel = ({ children }) => children;

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export default TabPanel;
```

**src/components/TabPanels/TabPanels.js**

```
import React, { Children } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const TabPanels = ({ activeIndex, children, className }) => (
  <div className={className}>{Children.toArray(children)[activeIndex]}</div>
);

TabPanels.propTypes = {
  activeIndex: PropTypes.number,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  setActiveIndex: PropTypes.func
};

export default TabPanels;
```

**src/components/TabPanels/index.js**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import TabPanels from "./TabPanels";

export default styled(TabPanels)`
  padding: 10px;
`;
```

**src/components/Tabs/Tabs.js**

```
import { Children, cloneElement, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import TabPanels from "../TabPanels";
import TabList from "../TabList";

const Tabs = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

  return Children.map(children, child => {
    switch (child.type) {
      case TabPanels: {
        return cloneElement(child, { activeIndex });
      }
      case TabList: {
        return cloneElement(child, {
          activeIndex,
          setActiveIndex
        });
      }
      default: {
        return child;
      }
    }
  });
};

Tabs.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export default Tabs;
```

**src/components/index.js**

```
export { default as Tab } from "./Tab";
export { default as TabContent } from "./TabContent";
export { default as TabList } from "./TabList";
export { default as TabPanel } from "./TabPanel";
export { default as TabPanels } from "./TabPanels";
export { default as Tabs } from "./Tabs";
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Tab,
  TabContent,
  Tabs,
  TabList,
  TabPanels,
  TabPanel
} from "./components";
import tabs from "./tabs";

const App = () => (
  <Tabs>
    <TabList>
      {tabs.map(({ icon, title, disabled }) => (
        <Tab key={title} disabled={disabled}>
          <TabContent>
            {icon} {title}
          </TabContent>
        </Tab>
      ))}
    </TabList>
    <TabPanels>
      {tabs.map(({ title, content }) => (
        <TabPanel key={title}>{content}</TabPanel>
      ))}
    </TabPanels>
  </Tabs>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**src/tabs.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { FaAppleAlt, FaCarrot, FaLemon } from "react-icons/fa";

export default [
  {
    title: "Apples",
    icon: <FaAppleAlt />,
    content: <p>Apples are delicious.</p>
  },
  {
    title: "Carrots",
    icon: <FaCarrot />,
    content: <p>Carrots are nutritious.</p>,
    disabled: true
  },
  {
    title: "Lemons",
    icon: <FaLemon />,
    content: <p>Lemons are ubiquitous.</p>
  }
];
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer and the CodeSandbox Matt, it is extremely helpful. I have done as you have suggested and created a separate styled component in a separate file called `AccordionRoot.js` which is then imported in `Accordion.js` and rendered where I was previously returning `<div>`. This same component is then referenced in Root styled component in `AccordionTrigger.js` rather than referencing `Accordion`. I can confirm this approach works and solves the dependency cycle problem!

Comment: Awesome! Glad you were able to figure it out!